# Eclipse - Improve performance and RAM usage

Tags: android, eclipse, performance, ram

What can I do to improve Eclipse from using all my computer resources? Eclipse is fast, but other programs are sluggish and mouse is unresponsive because of Eclipse. RAM is at 600 MB (Total 76% used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try setting VM settings in eclipse startup.

try http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

I set this in my shell script as "./eclipse -vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx1024m ...."

Comment: Okay I've changed the setting, the RAM usage is still the same, but Eclipse loaded in like 5 seconds, that's incredibly faster than usual. Is that the effect it should have had?

Comment: What are the settings you have set? can you put your settings and the shell command? How much memory do you have in total in the box? what sort of development are you planning to do with eclipse?

Comment: I have 4gb RAM total. I went into adt\eclipse\eclipse.ini and changed the setting manually. It was on Xms40m -Xmx568m.

Comment: ok, so you max memory is going to 568m, can you set -Xmx256m -Xms256m and see how much memory is used.

Also one question I have is if you are having 4GB and eclipse is using only 600m, how come it is showing 70% of memory used by eclipse.

Comment: I should clarify, all programs including Eclipse added together are using 70% of my 4gb. Sorry

Comment: Ok, if you only want to reduce memory of eclipse, then setting Xmx to a lower value will work but if you are doing heavy duty work with eclipse, you will need more memory. My advice is to look at your running programs and see if there are any apps that are not required to run, but taking up memory, to clean those out rather then reduce eclipse memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you open eclipse and 1 or 2 default android's emulator instances, you will run in low memory situations. I strongly recommend using VM hosted emulators like GenyMotion that is much faster than usual emulator. You can find GenyMotion here: http://www.genymotion.com

Comment: I use my own Phone device as the test device, Emulators run way too slow on my pc so I don't waste time with those.

Comment: OK, but you need to test your app with different sizes, resolutions, android versions and ... so take a look at GenyMotion!